# Installing the linux-virtual package from a preseed file

Tags: installation, kernel

I'm attempting to automate a server installation of Precise on a virtualbox VM. Eventually I'll use some of the preseed configuration to install it on a few ESXi VMS.

I would like to use the linux-virtual kernel package and the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/amd64/preseed-contents.html#preseed-base-installer) suggests that it is possible to change the kernel selection.

I currently have these lines in my preseed file

```
d-i base-installer/kernel/image string linux-virtual
d-i base-installer/kernel/altmeta string linux-virtual
```

I've also tried various other strings including linux-image-virtual.

Although linux-virtual is not on the server install CD, it is in the archive and I have the preseed file set up our local apt-cacher-ng instance:

```
d-i apt-setup/local0/repository string http://core:3142/gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main
d-i apt-setup/local1/repository string http://core:3142/gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
d-i apt-setup/local2/repository string http://core:3142/gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu   precise-security main
```

However during the installation I just get a selection menu which allows me to choose from various flavours of the generic kernel.

I'd like to install linux-virtual within the preseed so I can avoid the need to reboot again, as I would have to if I installed it after the installer had run.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the answer is that installing the linux-virtual package on 12.04.2 is pointless.

12.04.2 ships with a backported kernel from Quantal, the package is called linux-image-lts-quantal. In Quantal, the -virtual kernel package has been abolished, so there's no equivalent -virtual package.

It *is* possible to install the linux-virtual package after installation, but this will involve a downgrade from 3.5.0 to 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the leading linux-, that is implied.  I also don't think you need "base-installer/kernel/image", try leaving that as default.

Ref:
base-installer/kernel/altmeta
Description: for internal use; can be preseeded
 Optional postfix for kernel meta packages; can be used for example to
 support installation of an updated kernel for stable.
 Don't include the leading hyphen: it will be prepended in the code.

Comment: Removing all previous kernel selection lines and replacing them with

    d-i base-installer/kernel/altmeta string virtual

results in the installer kernel section screen.